# Developing application for devices with MIDP 2.0

Tags: eclipse, java-me, midp-2.0, eclipseme

I'm going to develop an application for devices with MIDP 2.0, Is it possible to do this using "Java ME SDK 3.0 for Windows"? or I have to install older versions? I use Eclipse and EclipseME plugin.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. It has profiles for different versions, and you can pick when you create your project.